# NSData Write to: не работает

Tags: json, swift, firebase

Всем привет! У меня есть два файла - .mov и .jpg. Они располагаются в Firebase Storage. У меня есть URL для их загрузки.
Что необходимо - 
Загрузить эти два файла и записать их локально. Далее воспользоваться local URL для того, чтобы к ним обратиться. Проблема заключается в том, что реакции на запись нет вообще никакой.

Ниже метод для загрузки из Firebase и записи данных -

```
    func observeLivePhotos() {
        let photosRef = Database.database().reference().child("Images")
        photosRef.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in

            for child in snapshot.children {
                if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
                let dict = childSnapshot.value as? [String: Any],
                let imageURL = dict["imageURL"] as? String,
                let placeholder = dict["placeholder"] as? String,
                let videoURL = dict["videoURL"] as? String,
                let URLimageURL = URL(string: imageURL),
                let placeholderURL = URL(string: placeholder),
                    let URLvideoURL = URL(string: videoURL) {
                    let livePhoto = LivePhotos(imageURL: URLimageURL, placeholder: placeholderURL, videoURL: URLvideoURL)
                    self.placeholderImageURL = livePhoto.placeholder
                    self.videoURL = livePhoto.videoURL
                    self.mainImageURL = livePhoto.imageURL

                    //GetVideo
                    let fileManager = FileManager.default
                    let urlForDownload = NSData(contentsOf: self.videoURL)
                    do {
                        let documentDirectory = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
                        let videoURLPath = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Video.mov")
                        urlForDownload?.write(to: videoURLPath, atomically: true)
                    }
                    catch {
                        print(error)
                    }

                    print(tempPhotos)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Смотрел в папке симулятора. Изменения идут только в файлах в папке Preferences. В Documents должно сохраняться, но там ничего, связанного с видео-файлом...
Ошибок никаких нет. Помогите, пожалуйста... Заранее, огромное спасибо :)

Comment: Так а данные вообще подтягиваются, проверили? Метод write что возвращает (true/false)?

Comment: @OlegSoloviev Привет! Нет, не проверял. Подскажи пожалуйста, как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Привет. Самый простой способ поставить print() везде, где проверяются условия, начинается цикл и т .д., print(child) и т.д.,  и посмотреть, выводятся ли данные в консоль. Если нет, то последовательно разбираться почему.

Comment: @OlegSoloviev . Хорошо! Сейчас проверю, отпишусь. Огромное спасибо за помощь :)

Comment: @OlegSoloviev , очень странно. Везде print() выставил и все заработало) Со вчерашнего дня xcode был открыт и сейчас просто заработало. Спасибо :) Напиши ответ, я тебе галочку поставлю.

Comment: Да не, от этого никак не зависит, видимо, что-то другое изменилось. За галочку спасибо, в след. раз ))